# Failed to claim interface WebUSB API

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, usb, webusb

After obtaining access to my usb device, I am trying to claim interface 0 on the device and get the error:
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'claimInterface' on 'USBDevice': Unable to claim interface.`

In `chrome://device-log/` I can see the following error:
`Interface 0 uses driver "silabser" instead of WinUSB.`

I am running on Windows 10.

I tried reconnecting the device, reinstalling the driver for windows to recognize the device.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `silabser` driver is a USB serial driver. If you don't need USB-level control over this device you can use the [Web Serial API](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/serial/) instead to access the device through the existing driver.

If you need to send custom USB commands then you will need to replace the `silabser` driver with the `winusb` driver using a tool like [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/).

Comment: Web Serial API was the way to go in my case.